# What is the difference between すみませんが and すみません?

Tags: usage, meaning

I'm still a beginner with japanese.

Here is the example that I foud: すみませんが、さとうをとってください

I'm not completely sure about the meaning of が in this sentence, since the teacher told me you can both use it or not. What is it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「が」 simply means "but".

> 「すみません**が**、さとうをとってください。」 =
>
> "Excuse me, ***but*** please pass me the sugar."

You can also make the same request without using 「が」 by saying:

> 「すみません。さとうをとってください。」 =
>
> "Excuse me.  Please pass me the sugar."

The difference between the two is almost too subtle to mention.  It just flows a little better with 「が」IMHO.

Comment: Could be weird to skip が in the case of not wanting to hurt anyone's feeling, where you would use 悪いけど in タメ語.

Comment: 「ガ」を入れて、自分のことを擁護になる可能性が高くなりますか。「すみませんが、それができません」の場合が多いですか。（非母語の人のセンス...）

Comment: @virmaior can you explain it in english, please?

Comment: My question was a clarification one for l'electeur, but I was wondering whether adding the "が" can add a sense of defense (think Socrates' *Apology*) versus contrition in non-が versions. It's a very *minor* point and one that doesn't at all affect the meaning of "が" which as l'electeur explains is "but". (I asked it in Japanese precisely because I felt it would only serve to confuse to add this sort fine-grained information).

Answer (score 1):

yes that's right. we can use the both sentence in the same sense.

> A: "すみません。さとうをとってください"
>   B: "すみませんが、さとうをとってください"

Note:
"すみませんが" or "申し訳ありませんが" or "恐れ入りますが"...etc
These are just like the Cushion.

A is just it has been completed.
B can be connected to the sentence after without punctuation.

> "すみませんさとうをとってください" NG
>   "すみませんがさとうをとってください" OK

adverb

> "さとうをとってください。すみません。" OK
>   "さとうをとってください。すみませんが。" NG

Comment: 私によって、この答えは悪くはないが、質問者は特に「が」の意味に気になっているため、ほぼ同じだけではなく、どのように変わっている教えて欲しいと思います。